# MVC Routes - Too Many?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have a small mvc app that uses predefined routes and I was wondering if that is the best approach if you would have a lot of routes? Say over 200+.

Route File

```
 $route->addGet('/page1', 'Controller@index');
 /* 200 More */
```

Comment: are you sure you are using the routes properly? can you post a few more that are actually real instead of your sample

Comment: Have you used `microtime(true)` to see how long adding and matching takes? If it is in microseconds, I wouldn't worry about it. Dealing with this may be a case of premature optimisation.

Comment: Maybe you can use groups or have a look at the Slim Microframework. Its easy to include.

Comment: After testing with a for loop and microtime, the difference between 1 route and 200 routes is only a few microseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes can be stored and used in other ways than how you are doing presently. You can store up your routes in a json file and call the correct controller using the file depending on how your controller works.

```
$routes = json_decode('json/file.json');
```

Will give you all routes in a php array, with that you can avoid writing them out in your php file.

I will advice taking a look at how other frameworks handle this problem (Silex, Slim, Symfony).

Answer (score 0):

Well, that does not matter if it gives a seamless flow the the end user. Though I am surprised to see that a small app has so many routes!